# Polynomial: $p(x) = p(x+3)$.

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

Determine polynomial $p(x)$ s.t. $p(x) = p(x+3)$.

---

Just by looking at the above equation, it immediately appears that p has got to be some kind of constant function. I thought it might also be a periodic function but, correct me as I am wrong, polynomials are not generally periodic functions and a constant function is the closest we get to a sort of periodic function (without the period).

My problem now is figuring out how to show this. Someone hinted that I might be able to do so by considering the polynomial 
$$q(x) = p (x) - p(x+3)$$
This expands out to something like
$$q (x) = a_n(x^n - (x+3)^n) + a_{n-1}(x^{n-1}-(x+3)^{n-1})...+ 3 a_1$$

Anyway, thoughts on where to go from here are appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ $\rm\:p(x)\:$ is constant $\rm = p(0)\:$ since $\rm\:p(x)-p(0)\:$ has infinitely many roots $\rm\:x = 0,3,6,9\ldots$ hence is the zero polynomial.

**Remark** $\ $ I presume that your polynomial has coefficients over some field such as $\rm\:\Bbb Q, \Bbb R, \Bbb C,\:$ where the subset $\rm\{0,3,6,\ldots\}$ is infinite. It may fail otherwise, e.g. $\rm\:p(x\!+\!3) = p(x)\:$ for all polynomials over $\rm\,\Bbb Z/3 =$ integers mod $3.$

Generally, that a polynomial with more roots than its degree must be the zero polynomial, is equivalent to: $ $ the coefficient ring $\rm\,R\,$ is an [integral domain,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain) i.e. for all $\rm\:\forall a,b\in R\!:\:$ $\rm\: ab=0\:\Rightarrow\:a=0\ \ or\ \ b=0.$

Comment: This is just what I was going to say as I was opening the question (+1).

Comment: I guess you also want the characteristic to be zero, so that  $0,3,6,\dots$ are distinct.

Comment: @Andreas Indeed. I've edited to clarify that. Thanks.

Comment: My apologies for being obnoxious, but the set $0,3,6,\dots$ is infinite *if and only if* the characteristic is zero.

Comment: @Andreas It was a conscious decision to not state it in more algebraic language, since the OP did not tag it abstract algebra, so they may not know what "characteristic" means. But I might (and have often) made similar remarks. So your remarks are very welcome (certainly not obnoxious).

Comment: Ok, I see your point, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

An addendum to the other answers. You did not specify a field. In positive characteristic $p \ne 3$ there are non-constant polynomials with this property,  for instance 
$$
x (x+3) (x+3 \cdot 2) \dots (x + 3 (p-1)). 
$$

In characteristic $3$ the  condition of course holds for all polynomials.

Comment: In characteristic $3$, the condition reduces to $p(x)=p(x)$. Not terribly interesting :-)

Comment: @robjohn That's what I also said.

Comment: +1 For emphasizing the pitfalls in nonzero characteristic.

Comment: @MathGems, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

All of the above answers are algebraic. Let's get some calculus argument:

Every non-constant polynomial has $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} p(x)=\pm\infty$. But for a polynomial with $p(x)=p(x+3)$, you can take the sequence $x_n=x_0+3\cdot n$, which clearly advances to $\infty$ and yields $p(x_n)=p(x_{n-1}+3)=p(x_{n-1})=\ldots=p(x_0)$, which is a constant sequence. So for this polynomial $p(x)$ $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} p(x)=\pm\infty$ is clearly wrong and the polynomial has to be constant.

Answer (score 1):

Math Gems answer is what you're looking for. However, I just wanted to add something interesting. I'm assuming the $x$ in your question is a real number, integer, etc. However, if you allow $x$ to be an element of a finite field, then it doesn't follow that "periodic" polynomials must be zero. For example consider, $p(x)=x^{p}-x \in \Bbb F_{p}[x]$, then:

$p(x+3)=(x+3)^{p}-(x+3)=x^{p}+3^{p}-x-3=x^{p}+3-x-3=x^{p}-x=p(x)$.

The important facts here are in a field of characteristic $p$, $(x+y)^{p}=x^{p}+y^{p}$ and $a^{p}=a$. Also, the $3$ wasn't particularly important here, and could be replaced with any integer.

Comment: But as $a^p = a$, it follows that for any value $x$, we have $p(x) = x^p - x = x - x = 0$: i.e., the polynomial takes value 0 everywhere, even if it is not the zero polynomial.